# What's the probability of having n equal numbers in different slots between 00000 and 600000

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say you're trying to figure out which lottery ticket to buy for the weekend. Although, the chances of winning are slim, you think that maybe knowing how likely it is that there are $n\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ instances of the same number in different slots on a ticket with numbers from 00000 to 60000 will help.

What are the chances of having $n\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ instances of the same number in a random ticket with values between 00000 and 60000?


Is there a way to generalize this for chains of slots that are $k$ digits in length going from $000\dots00n$  to  $m00\dots000$ with $0\leq n \leq 9$ and $1\leq m \leq  9$ ?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Where are you stuck ? You could experiment with a small number of digits to see if a pattern emerges.

Comment: Well, it's giving me a hard time, but that's because I refused to learn combinatorics until today. I've managed to come up with an inequality though $n_{5} \leq n_{4} \leq n_{0} \leq n_{3} \leq n_{2} \leq n_{1} $ where $n_{k}$ is the number of times $k$ numbers have been repeated in the string

Comment: If you have two of one number, three of another, etc, what are you counting ?

Comment: the number of repetitions a number has in a string

Comment: "Well, it's giving me a hard time, but that's because I refused to learn combinatorics until today."  It is not a good idea to jump in the ocean, before first trying to swim in a pool.  Although, superficially, [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) is on point, the larger question is how (in general) to approach these types of mathematical situations.  I advise finding the right book, and opening it to page 1.

Answer (score 1):

Taking it to mean you want to count the number of times a *particular* digit repeats in the string:

For *k* repetitions of a particular digit:

*(a): The particular digit occurs in the first digit and (k-1) others*

$\binom1 1\binom 5 {k-1}9^{(6-k)}$

*(b): The particular digit doesn't occur in the first digit*

$\binom51\binom5{k}9^{(5-k)}$

Work out and add up